# Convert image from float64 to uint8 makes the image look darker

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing, scikit-image

I have images of type float64 generated by GANs, and I save them through [`skimage.io.imsave`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave). The process works well and the saved image looks nice, but I get a warning message as follows:

> Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [-0.9999998807907104, 0.9999175071716309]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.

Then I try to get rid of this warning by convert images to uint8 before saving using function [`skimage.img_as_ubyte`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html#skimage.img_as_ubyte). This gives me a apparently much darker image with a warning

> UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint8
>     .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))

I've also tried to use other functions such as the one from tensorflow [`tf.image.convert_image_dtype`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype) before saving. They all return a darker image than I directly call skimage.io.imsave. What's the problem here?

Here's a set of images generated by converting to uint8 before saving
[image]

Here's a set of images generated by saving directly
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the documentation of `skimage.img_as_ubyte` that you linked](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html#skimage.img_as_ubyte):

> Negative input values will be clipped. Positive values are scaled between 0 and 255.

Since your images are in the range [-1,1], half of the data will be set to 0, which is why stuff looks darker. Try first scaling your image to a positive-only range, for example by adding 1 to it, before calling `skimage.img_as_ubyte`.

Answer (score 8):

I fix this warning by using,

```py
import numpy as np
import imageio

# suppose that img's dtype is 'float64'
img_uint8 = img.astype(np.uint8)
# and then
imageio.imwrite('filename.jpg', img_uint8)
```

That's it!